# What's the reason why we must flush data cache after copy code from flash to ram?

Tags: caching, embedded, bootloader, u-boot, flash-memory

In embedded system, boot-loader used to init the board and load image. Usually,  boot-loader runs in norflash during the 1st stage and need copy itself (.txte+.date code) from flash to ram, then jump to ram execute code.

My question is: when copy code from flash to RAM and cache enable, do we must flush data cache and invalidate the instruction cache? I found uboot and other bootloader execute this operation, but if I don't do that, the system still could boot successful, what's the reason why we must flush data cache after copy code from flash to ram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple embedded MCUs usually do not have any means to "snoop" the bus checking if anybody (even itself) invalidates cache contents with writes to cached memory addresses.

If your MCU has separate data and instruction caches (which most modern MCUs have) and you copy code as data from flash to RAM, you need to flush the data cache (to ensure everything you copied is physically written to RAM) and invalidate the instruction cache (which might contain "old" information from before the copy) to really execute the code you just copied instead of executing what was there before and still resides in instruction cache.

You might get away *not* doing the latter if you can be sure your MCU has never "seen" the memory area before you just copied (since it will not have cached anything and needs to physically read RAM anyway), but it's good practice to do data cache flushes and instruction cache invalidation nevertheless to stay on the safe side.

Copying code from flash to RAM *is* a special case of self modifying code and you as a programmer need to make sure it's doing no damage.

Comment: Thanks mfro! Really appreciate for you explanation. The MCU is PowerPC QorIq T1040, which has separate L1 data and instruction caches.Only enable the L1 cache,L2/L3 disabled. I still have two 2 questions, any thoughts would be appreciate .1

Comment: the comment too long so I post a answer, I'm a newer on stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think a main reason can be found in "more than one core" CPUs. Very important in case of **asymmetrical cores**, eg. i.MX6SoloX (Cortex A9 and Cortex M4 on single chip).

For example in i.MX6SoloX if the slave core **(M5)** run on **RAM (DDR)** the **main core (A9)** is the main cpu that has to provide the **M4 core** code loaded into **RAM** at the correct position. Those cores have different D-caches  that don't see each other. If the A9 core, after the FLASH to RAM copy, doesn’t flush it’s D-Chache, some part of code is not copied to RAM actually, because of still in D-Cache memory. If you perform this copy from u-boot you can see that A9 (that is running U-Boot) see all data correctly copied, but the M4 see all code, but not the code that still in D-Cache of A9 core.

In your case (a single core like you, I guess) is not mandatory that U-Boot flush the D-cache (after the kernel copy I guess), because the owner of the D-cache is the core itself: it can see its code inside all its memories.

At the very end the reason is that to grant that a performed data copy completely wrote data to a specific address you have to flush D-Cache, otherwise some data can still in caches.

Comment: this (mandatory or not) depends on the platform. Some (most?) have separate instruction and data caches. In that case you must flush the data cache even with a single core for the instruction cache to pick up.